# Combining Google sheet scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this sheet that runs multiple onEdit's and time triggered scripts.

Most of the scripts have the same function but has different triggers and it slows down my sheet overall. I'm not an expert at this so and I'm looking to combine scripts so I can keep the amount scripts to a minimum.

Any help would be appreciated.

There is 2 types of functions that I'm looking for to combine.

**The first one**

This function moves rows from a main sheet called Pipe to different destination sheets within the spreadsheet when triggered

**The second one**

This function makes counts to a backlog sheet when cell/columns are edited in the same main sheet called Pipe

Here is a link to a copy of my sheet with the scripts in it: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17RTTZmoIRpA4uFkaLFuFZJSPDW5sRhEQgB8B4mwln5U/edit?usp=sharing

Here are all of the scripts that I'm looking to combine down below.

**First function script**

```js
function BokadM1() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange();
    
      if(s.getName() == "Pipe" && r.getColumn() == 8 && r.getValue() != "") {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Bokad");
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        s.getRange(row, 2, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target).range.clearContent();
        
      }
    }

function Ombokad() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange();
    
      if(s.getName() == "Pipe" && r.getColumn() == 13 && r.getValue() != "") {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Bokad");
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        s.getRange(row, 2, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target).range.clearContent();
        
      }
    }

function ÅkM1() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange();
    
      if(s.getName() == "Pipe" && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() != "") {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Återkomster");
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        s.getRange(row, 2, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target).range.clearContent();
       
      }
    }

    

function NejM1() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange();
    
      if(s.getName() == "Pipe" && r.getColumn() == 9 && r.getValue() != "") {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Nej");
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        s.getRange(row, 2, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target).range.clearContent();
       
      }
    }

function AvtalM1() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange();
    
      if(s.getName() == "Pipe" && r.getColumn() == 10 && r.getValue() != "") {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Avtal");
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        s.getRange(row, 2, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target).range.clearContent();
       
      }
    }

function Snitt() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange();
    
      if(s.getName() == "Pipe" && r.getColumn() == 8 && r.getValue() != "") {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Snitt");
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        s.getRange(row, 5, 1, 1).copyTo(target);
        
      }
    }
```

**Second function script**

```js
function Samtal(e) {
  const sheetToWatch = 'Pipe';
  const targetSs = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rRENZjpQzdq0xugBPkMjltz2AIpYPWHH_sThh5r9x3A/edit#gid=618446899") //id of spreadsheet
  const targetSheet = 'Brain'; //fill in name of other sheet/tab
  const countColumn = 1; // column G
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (!e.value
      || sheet.getName() !== sheetToWatch
      || e.range.rowStart <= (sheet.getFrozenRows() || 1)
      || e.range.columnStart !== 5) {
    return;
  }
  // increment count
  const countCell = targetSs.getSheetByName(targetSheet).getRange(e.range.rowStart, countColumn); 
  countCell.setValue((Number(countCell.getValue()) || 0) + 1);
}

function Samtal2(e) {
  const sheetToWatch = 'Pipe';
  const targetSs = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rRENZjpQzdq0xugBPkMjltz2AIpYPWHH_sThh5r9x3A/edit#gid=618446899") //id of spreadsheet
  const targetSheet = 'Brain'; //fill in name of other sheet/tab
  const countColumn = 15; // column G
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (!e.value
      || sheet.getName() !== sheetToWatch
      || e.range.rowStart <= (sheet.getFrozenRows() || 1)
      || e.range.columnStart !== 5) {
    return;
  }
  // increment count
  const countCell = targetSs.getSheetByName(targetSheet).getRange(e.range.rowStart, countColumn); 
  countCell.setValue((Number(countCell.getValue()) || 0) + 1);
}

function Email(e) {
  const sheetToWatch = 'Pipe';
  const targetSs = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rRENZjpQzdq0xugBPkMjltz2AIpYPWHH_sThh5r9x3A/edit#gid=618446899") //id of spreadsheet
  const targetSheet = 'Brain'; //fill in name of other sheet/tab
  const countColumn = 2; // column G
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (!e.value
      || sheet.getName() !== sheetToWatch
      || e.range.rowStart <= (sheet.getFrozenRows() || 1)
      || e.range.columnStart !== 6) {
    return;
  }
  // increment count
  const countCell = targetSs.getSheetByName(targetSheet).getRange(e.range.rowStart, countColumn); 
  countCell.setValue((Number(countCell.getValue()) || 0) + 1);
}

function Email2(e) {
  const sheetToWatch = 'Pipe';
  const targetSs = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rRENZjpQzdq0xugBPkMjltz2AIpYPWHH_sThh5r9x3A/edit#gid=618446899") //id of spreadsheet
  const targetSheet = 'Brain'; //fill in name of other sheet/tab
  const countColumn = 16; // column G
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (!e.value
      || sheet.getName() !== sheetToWatch
      || e.range.rowStart <= (sheet.getFrozenRows() || 1)
      || e.range.columnStart !== 6) {
    return;
  }
  // increment count
  const countCell = targetSs.getSheetByName(targetSheet).getRange(e.range.rowStart, countColumn); 
  countCell.setValue((Number(countCell.getValue()) || 0) + 1);
}

function Åk(e) {
  const sheetToWatch = 'Pipe';
  const targetSs = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rRENZjpQzdq0xugBPkMjltz2AIpYPWHH_sThh5r9x3A/edit#gid=618446899") //id of spreadsheet
  const targetSheet = 'Brain'; //fill in name of other sheet/tab
  const countColumn = 3; // column G
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (!e.value
      || sheet.getName() !== sheetToWatch
      || e.range.rowStart <= (sheet.getFrozenRows() || 1)
      || e.range.columnStart !== 7) {
    return;
  }
  // increment count
  const countCell = targetSs.getSheetByName(targetSheet).getRange(e.range.rowStart, countColumn); 
  countCell.setValue((Number(countCell.getValue()) || 0) + 1);
}

function Åk2(e) {
  const sheetToWatch = 'Pipe';
  const targetSs = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rRENZjpQzdq0xugBPkMjltz2AIpYPWHH_sThh5r9x3A/edit#gid=618446899") //id of spreadsheet
  const targetSheet = 'Brain'; //fill in name of other sheet/tab
  const countColumn = 17; // column G
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (!e.value
      || sheet.getName() !== sheetToWatch
      || e.range.rowStart <= (sheet.getFrozenRows() || 1)
      || e.range.columnStart !== 7) {
    return;
  }
  // increment count
  const countCell = targetSs.getSheetByName(targetSheet).getRange(e.range.rowStart, countColumn); 
  countCell.setValue((Number(countCell.getValue()) || 0) + 1);
}
function Bokad(e) {
  if (e.oldValue) return;
  const sheetToWatch = 'Pipe';
  const targetSs = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rRENZjpQzdq0xugBPkMjltz2AIpYPWHH_sThh5r9x3A/edit#gid=618446899") //id of spreadsheet
  const targetSheet = 'Brain'; //fill in name of other sheet/tab
  const countColumn = 4; // column G
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (!e.value 
      || sheet.getName() !== sheetToWatch
      || e.range.rowStart <= (sheet.getFrozenRows() || 1)
      || e.range.columnStart !== 8)
       {
    return;
  }
  // increment count
  const countCell = targetSs.getSheetByName(targetSheet).getRange(e.range.rowStart, countColumn); 
  countCell.setValue((Number(countCell.getValue()) || 0) + 1);
}

function Bokad2(e) {
  if (e.oldValue) return;
  const sheetToWatch = 'Pipe';
  const targetSs = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rRENZjpQzdq0xugBPkMjltz2AIpYPWHH_sThh5r9x3A/edit#gid=618446899") //id of spreadsheet
  const targetSheet = 'Brain'; //fill in name of other sheet/tab
  const countColumn = 18; // column G
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (!e.value
      || sheet.getName() !== sheetToWatch
      || e.range.rowStart <= (sheet.getFrozenRows() || 1)
      || e.oldvalue == ""
      || e.range.columnStart !== 8)
       {
    return;
  }
  // increment count
  const countCell = targetSs.getSheetByName(targetSheet).getRange(e.range.rowStart, countColumn); 
  countCell.setValue((Number(countCell.getValue()) || 0) + 1);
}

function Nej(e) {
  const sheetToWatch = 'Pipe';
  const targetSs = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rRENZjpQzdq0xugBPkMjltz2AIpYPWHH_sThh5r9x3A/edit#gid=618446899") //id of spreadsheet
  const targetSheet = 'Brain'; //fill in name of other sheet/tab
  const countColumn = 5; // column G
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (!e.value
      || sheet.getName() !== sheetToWatch
      || e.range.rowStart <= (sheet.getFrozenRows() || 1)
      || e.range.columnStart !== 9) {
    return;
  }
  // increment count
  const countCell = targetSs.getSheetByName(targetSheet).getRange(e.range.rowStart, countColumn); 
  countCell.setValue((Number(countCell.getValue()) || 0) + 1);
}

function Nej2(e) {
  const sheetToWatch = 'Pipe';
  const targetSs = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rRENZjpQzdq0xugBPkMjltz2AIpYPWHH_sThh5r9x3A/edit#gid=618446899") //id of spreadsheet
  const targetSheet = 'Brain'; //fill in name of other sheet/tab
  const countColumn = 19; // column G
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (!e.value
      || sheet.getName() !== sheetToWatch
      || e.range.rowStart <= (sheet.getFrozenRows() || 1)
      || e.range.columnStart !== 9) {
    return;
  }
  // increment count
  const countCell = targetSs.getSheetByName(targetSheet).getRange(e.range.rowStart, countColumn); 
  countCell.setValue((Number(countCell.getValue()) || 0) + 1);
}

function Avtal(e) {
  const sheetToWatch = 'Pipe';
  const targetSs = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rRENZjpQzdq0xugBPkMjltz2AIpYPWHH_sThh5r9x3A/edit#gid=618446899") //id of spreadsheet
  const targetSheet = 'Brain'; //fill in name of other sheet/tab
  const countColumn = 6; // column G
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (!e.value
      || sheet.getName() !== sheetToWatch
      || e.range.rowStart <= (sheet.getFrozenRows() || 1)
      || e.range.columnStart !== 10) {
    return;
  }
  // increment count
  const countCell = targetSs.getSheetByName(targetSheet).getRange(e.range.rowStart, countColumn); 
  countCell.setValue((Number(countCell.getValue()) || 0) + 1);
}

function Avtal2(e) {
  const sheetToWatch = 'Pipe';
  const targetSs = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rRENZjpQzdq0xugBPkMjltz2AIpYPWHH_sThh5r9x3A/edit#gid=618446899") //id of spreadsheet
  const targetSheet = 'Brain'; //fill in name of other sheet/tab
  const countColumn = 20; // column G
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (!e.value
      || sheet.getName() !== sheetToWatch
      || e.range.rowStart <= (sheet.getFrozenRows() || 1)
      || e.range.columnStart !== 10) {
    return;
  }
  // increment count
  const countCell = targetSs.getSheetByName(targetSheet).getRange(e.range.rowStart, countColumn); 
  countCell.setValue((Number(countCell.getValue()) || 0) + 1);
}

function Gmöte(e) {
  const sheetToWatch = 'Pipe';
  const targetSs = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rRENZjpQzdq0xugBPkMjltz2AIpYPWHH_sThh5r9x3A/edit#gid=618446899") //id of spreadsheet
  const targetSheet = 'Brain'; //fill in name of other sheet/tab
  const countColumn = 7; // column G
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (!e.value
      || sheet.getName() !== sheetToWatch
      || e.range.rowStart <= (sheet.getFrozenRows() || 1)
      || e.range.columnStart !== 12) {
    return;
  }
  // increment count
  const countCell = targetSs.getSheetByName(targetSheet).getRange(e.range.rowStart, countColumn); 
  countCell.setValue((Number(countCell.getValue()) || 0) + 1);
}

function Gmöte2(e) {
  const sheetToWatch = 'Pipe';
  const targetSs = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rRENZjpQzdq0xugBPkMjltz2AIpYPWHH_sThh5r9x3A/edit#gid=618446899") //id of spreadsheet
  const targetSheet = 'Brain'; //fill in name of other sheet/tab
  const countColumn = 21; // column G
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (!e.value
      || sheet.getName() !== sheetToWatch
      || e.range.rowStart <= (sheet.getFrozenRows() || 1)
      || e.range.columnStart !== 12) {
    return;
  }
  // increment count
  const countCell = targetSs.getSheetByName(targetSheet).getRange(e.range.rowStart, countColumn); 
  countCell.setValue((Number(countCell.getValue()) || 0) + 1);
}


function Offert(e) {
  const sheetToWatch = 'Pipe';
  const targetSs = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rRENZjpQzdq0xugBPkMjltz2AIpYPWHH_sThh5r9x3A/edit#gid=618446899") //id of spreadsheet
  const targetSheet = 'Brain'; //fill in name of other sheet/tab
  const countColumn = 8; // column G
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (!e.value
      || sheet.getName() !== sheetToWatch
      || e.range.rowStart <= (sheet.getFrozenRows() || 1)
      || e.range.columnStart !== 14) {
    return;
  }
  // increment count
  const countCell = targetSs.getSheetByName(targetSheet).getRange(e.range.rowStart, countColumn); 
  countCell.setValue((Number(countCell.getValue()) || 0) + 1);
}


function Offert2(e) {
  const sheetToWatch = 'Pipe';
  const targetSs = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rRENZjpQzdq0xugBPkMjltz2AIpYPWHH_sThh5r9x3A/edit#gid=618446899") //id of spreadsheet
  const targetSheet = 'Brain'; //fill in name of other sheet/tab
  const countColumn = 22; // column G
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (!e.value
      || sheet.getName() !== sheetToWatch
      || e.range.rowStart <= (sheet.getFrozenRows() || 1)
      || e.range.columnStart !== 14) {
    return;
  }
  // increment count
  const countCell = targetSs.getSheetByName(targetSheet).getRange(e.range.rowStart, countColumn); 
  countCell.setValue((Number(countCell.getValue()) || 0) + 1);
}
```

So I got feedback on using the Switch function that I think is a great idea, I'm not sure exactly how to implement it in script but here is my draft and I would really appreciate any input.

That is a great idea and just so I understand this since I'm not a expert on this:

Do you mean something like this?

```html
function allInOne(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var r = e.range;
  var sheet = range.sheet;
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  if (e.value != "") {
    if (sheetName == "Pipe" {
      switch (r.getColumn()) {
        case 7:
          if(r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() != "") {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Återkomster");
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        s.getRange(row, 2, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target).range.clearContent();
       
      }
    }// do column 7 tasks
          break;
        case 8:
          if(r.getColumn() == 8 && r.getValue() != "") {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Bokad");
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        s.getRange(row, 2, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target).range.clearContent();
        
      }
    }// do column 8 tasks
          break;
        case 13:
          if(r.getColumn() == 13 && r.getValue() != "") {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Bokad");
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        s.getRange(row, 2, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target).range.clearContent();
        
      }
```

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. 1) `onEdit(e)` scripts are in `Second function script` group. 2) Time-driven scripts are in `First function script` group. 3) All triggers are installable. Would you please also explain interval/frequency of time-driven triggers, provide data to support your claim that scripts `slows down my sheet overall`, describe your efforts to solve your problem, and describe your scenario and data layout. Please don't assume that users will open your spreadsheet to better understand your question; any information about your spreadsheet should be included in your question.

Comment: Have you considered using `switch` to create a single `onEdit` function? You have 10 basically identical functions, and `Bokad`/`Bokad2` are only slightly different. Everything could be consolidated in a single function with `columnStart` as the `switch` expression.

Comment: Regarding the time-driven triggers... you have 5 are basically identical - `getColumn`, `targetSheet`, and `Column` being the variables. The variables could be assigned to arrays, and a single function created containing a loop that cycles through the combinations. `Snitt` is the only exception, but since it has a different column number (5) an IF statement could distinguish between the logic for it vs the rest.

Comment: Is `Brain` in another spreadsheet or the same?  If it is in the same simply `.getSheetByName()` rather than `openByUrl()`

Comment: @TheWizEd The `targetSs` is an external sheet; the url is identical in every script. `Brain` is a sheet in `targetSs`.

Comment: There is so much duplication in each function its hard to debug.  But at first glance, move `const targetSs = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rRENZjpQzdq0xugBPkMjltz2AIpYPWHH_sThh5r9x3A/edit#gid=618446899") //id of spreadsheet` after `// increment count`.  You shouldn't open it each time. Only if it passes the conditions.

Comment: @Tedinoz All of them are onEdit's script and I have used a single onEdit(e) { function1, function2 etc } to group them all together. I realized that this might not be the best way to approach this and if I have understod this correctly it will go through of all of the onEdits until it finds the right one that triggered and therefore it takes some time before it gets triggerd. I have googled around and I'm looking to make them to 2 functions (If possible) since they all have the same functions but different Col's that triggers and different destination Col's and sheets within the spreadsheet.

Comment: @TheWizEd Brain is a sheet within the same spreadsheet

Comment: `and I have used a single onEdit(e) { function1, function2 etc }` You might have mentioned that earlier. `I'm looking to make them to 2 functions` - that's wise, and that's why I suggested `switch`. So, do you actually have a problem?

Comment: @Tedinoz I see that I missed it and sorry about that. Well yes since I'm not a expert in writing these scripts, I understans more and more and the logic around things but there is a lot that I still don't know. Switch is a great suggestion and I also got that tip from the google community. Here is a draft on the first function script.

Comment: @Tedinoz I have added the draft in the post, would appreciate if you could take a look and see if I have understood it or if something is wrong

Comment: `I have added the draft in the post` I _did_ think that switch would work, but there are two separate variables in each function (`columnStart` and `countColumn`) and `switch` is not a good solution for these. I have posted an answer that includes my comments on processing logic.

Answer (score 0):

**Combining Functions#1:**  => allInOne01(e)

`Samtal(e)`, `Samtal2(e)`, `Åk(e)`, `Åk2(e)`, `Email1(e)`,  `Email2(e)`, `Nej(e)`,  `Nej2(e)`,  `Avtal(e)`and `Avtal2(e)`

These functions are identical except for the `columnStart` and `countColumn` values. I initially proposed `switch` as a solution to combine these into a single function but I found that this didn't suit the two variable criterion.

Instead, the processing logic uses:

- an array to hold  the "column sets" ("columnStart" and 2 x "countColumn" values).
  `const colSets = [[5,1,15],[6,2,16],[7,3,17],[9,5,19],[10,6,20]];`
- `indexOf` to selection the appropriate column set

  - `const countColumn1 = colSets[result][1];`
  - `const countColumn2 = colSets[result][2];`

I've left some code descriptions and Logger statements in the script to assist the user. The effective code length is 22 lines compared to 16 lines for **each** of the previous functions.

---

**Combining Functions#2:**  => allInOne02(e)

`Bokad(e)` and `Bokad2(e)`

These functions vary by only one or two lines from the other functions. But since they *do* vary, I have combined them separately.

---

```
function allInOne01(e) {

  // some variables  
  const sheetToWatch = 'Pipe';
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();

  // test if edit is is a value, AND in correct Sheet AND in correct row
  if (!e.value || sheet.getName() !== sheetToWatch || e.range.rowStart <= (sheet.getFrozenRows() || 1))
  {
    // if failed end processing
    return;
  }

  // an array of Column Sets
  const colSets = [[5,1,15],[6,2,16],[7,3,17],[9,5,19],[10,6,20]]; // columnCtart, countColumn#1,countColumn#2
  // create an array of columnStart values
  var columns = colSets.map(function(e){return e[0];});
  // find the columnStart in columns
  var result = columns.indexOf(e.range.columnStart);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: result = "+result)
  if (result !== -1){ // if -1, then value not found, otherwise value = zero-based index
    const targetSs = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rRENZjpQzdq0xugBPkMjltz2AIpYPWHH_sThh5r9x3A/edit#gid=618446899") //id of spreadsheet
    const targetSheetName = 'Brain'; //fill in name of other sheet/tab
    const targetSheet = targetSs.getSheetByName(targetSheetName)
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: CountColumn#1: "+colSets[result][1])
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: CountColumn#2: "+colSets[result][2])
    const countColumn1 = colSets[result][1]; 
    const countColumn2 = colSets[result][2]; 
    // increment count1
    const countCell1 = targetSheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, countColumn1); 
    countCell1.setValue((Number(countCell1.getValue()) || 0) + 1);
    // increment count2
    const countCell2 = targetSheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, countColumn2); 
    countCell2.setValue((Number(countCell2.getValue()) || 0) + 1);
    // Logger.log('DEBUG: Complete');
  }
}
```

---

```
function allInOne02(e) {
  if (e.oldValue) return;

   // some variables  
  const sheetToWatch = 'Pipe';
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();

  // test if edit is is a value, AND in correct Sheet AND in correct row
  if (!e.value || sheet.getName() !== sheetToWatch || e.range.rowStart <= (sheet.getFrozenRows() || 1))
  {
    // if failed end processing
    return;
  }

  // an array of Column Sets
  const colSets = [[8,4,18]]; // columnCtart, countColumn#1,countColumn#2
  // create an array of columnStart values
  var columns = colSets.map(function(e){return e[0];});
  // find the columnStart in columns
  var result = columns.indexOf(e.range.columnStart);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: result = "+result)
  if (result !== -1){ // if -1, then value not found, otherwise value = zero-based index
    const targetSs = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rRENZjpQzdq0xugBPkMjltz2AIpYPWHH_sThh5r9x3A/edit#gid=618446899") //id of spreadsheet
    const targetSheetName = 'Brain'; //fill in name of other sheet/tab
    const targetSheet = targetSs.getSheetByName(targetSheetName)
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: CountColumn#1: "+colSets[result][1])
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: CountColumn#2: "+colSets[result][2])
    const countColumn1 = colSets[result][1]; 
    const countColumn2 = colSets[result][2]; 
    // increment count1
    const countCell1 = targetSheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, countColumn1); 
    countCell1.setValue((Number(countCell1.getValue()) || 0) + 1);
    // increment count2
    const countCell2 = targetSheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, countColumn2); 
    countCell2.setValue((Number(countCell2.getValue()) || 0) + 1);
    // Logger.log('DEBUG: Complete');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Tried it out and it doesn't make the counts. I don't know why, any ideas?

Comment: My mistake. I didn't update the `setValue` for `countCell2` (2nd last line in each script). it did read `countCell1.setValue((Number(countCell2.getValue()) || 0) + 1);` and should read `countCell2.setValue((Number(countCell2.getValue()) || 0) + 1);`. Fixed, updated answer; should be OK.

Comment: BTW, don't understand why you use `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl` since this is the same spreadsheet as as contains all the other data. But... it does work.

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you for the help, it is much appreciated! I know and I hade getactivespreadsheet before but for some reason it didn't trigger so I changed it but yeah it works, maybe not the optimal solution but as long as it works